# Should I create table drop migration for unused tables?

Tags: php, laravel, migration

A simple question for which I could not find the answer on google.

I have a Laravel 5.2 based project where some tables are no longer needed: is the correct way to create a migration with `dropIfExists` in it or should I just manually drop it and delete the migration responsible for the creation of the table?

On one hand, the migration gives me a rollback option, where I can recreate the table, but on the other hand, it is still stupid to create a table and then drop it again later. And the migration ( if suddenly needed ) can be always found in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can just drop or delete yor migration file for the tables which are not in use, define `php artisan make:model test --migration` only when there is a need to create a migration file. 
Or else if there is any need afterwards then create migration file for the same with `php artisan make:migration`.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that or you can do a hack by modifying the value of `batch` Column in your `migrations` table

`php artisan migrate:rollback` command looks for the largest `batch` value in the `migrations` table and delete the corresponding table.
E.g: if you have `1,1,1,2,3,4,4` in your `batch` column and you run the `rollback` command it will delete all tables with the value `4`.

Therefore, in your case increase all the `batch` value of your unwanted tables and run the `rollback` command.

Comment: This is not wrong, but rather missing some info. This trick will work only if those rolled-back migrations have an actual rollback action (like `Schema::dropTable(...)`) in their `down()` definition. If not, OP has to either add the rollback action to existing migration, or create a new migration that drops the unused tables.